ElasticSearch related error after upgrading springboot app from 2.x to 3.1.0
I'm new to Elastic search and the first I got is to upgrade springboot version from 2.x to 3.1.0
After the upgrade, the app is running without any issues in local but when deploying in server and running getting below error :
Error creating bean with name 'storeDetailsRepo' defined in com.xyz.abc.communication.elk.repository.ElkStoreDetailsRepo defined in @EnableElasticsearchRepositories declared on ElasticsearchRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableElasticsearchRepositoriesConfiguration: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'elasticsearchTemplate' while setting bean property 'elasticsearchOperations'
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataConfiguration$JavaClientConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'elasticsearchTemplate' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchClientConfigurations$ElasticsearchClientConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'elasticsearchClient' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'restClientTransport' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchClientConfigurations$ElasticsearchTransportConfiguration.class]: Signature Parse error: expected a class type

Maven dependecy Tree:
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:jar:5.1.0:compile
[INFO]       \- co.elastic.clients:elasticsearch-java:jar:8.7.1:compile

